# Error while consuming AVRO Kafka Topic from KSQL Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created some dummydata as a Stream in KSQLDB with
`VALUE_FORMAT='JSON' TOPIC='MYTOPIC'`

The Setup is over Docker-compose. I am running a Kafka Broker, Schema-registry, ksqldbcli, ksqldb-server, zookeeper

Now I want to consume these records from the topic.
My first and last approach was over the commandline with following command

```
docker run  --net=host  --rm  confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.0  kafka-avro-console-consumer
--bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --topic DXT --from-beginning --max-messages 10
--property print.key=true --property print.value=true
--value-deserializer io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
--key-deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

But that just returns the error

```
[2021-04-22 21:45:42,926] ERROR Unknown error when running consumer:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$:76)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

I also tried it with different use cases in Java Spring but with no prevail. I just cannot consume the created topics.
If I would need to define my own schema, where should I do that and what would be the easiest way because I just created a stream in Ksqldb?
Is there an easy to follow example. I did not specifiy anything else when I created the stream like in the quickstart example on [Ksqldb.io](https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html). (I added the schema-registry in my deployment)
As I am a noob that is sitting here for almost 10 hours any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I found that pure JSON does not need the Schema-registry with ksqldb. [Here](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.15.0-ksqldb/reference/serialization/#json).
But how to deserialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've written JSON data to the topic then you can read it with the `kafka-console-consumer`.

The error you're getting (`Error deserializing Avro message for id -1…Unknown magic byte!`) is because you're using the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` which attempts to deserialise the topic data as Avro - which it isn't, hence the error.

You can also use `PRINT DXT;` from within ksqlDB.

Comment: So simple but oh so good.
Thank you for saving my sleep. It finally works lol

Comment: Glad it worked - if it answered your question please do mark it as answered to help others find it in the future :)